# Launch UIActivity without UIActivityViewController?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiactivityviewcontroller

Was wondering if it's possible to launch a `UIActivity` from my own menu with my own buttons, rather than having to launch a `UIActivityViewController`. I do know that it's possible using `MFMailComposeViewController`, `TWTweetComposeViewController`, etc, but wondering if there is some way that it's all consolidated into `UIActivity` so don't have to use a separate API for each individual `UIActivity`.

Comment: Can u elaborate or clearify you question.. what you want to do?

Comment: @AhmedZ. Want to take a UIActivity and launch it without using a UIActivityViewController. You know how UIActivityViewController presents a modalView with buttons? I'd rather launch it from some custom menu that I make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible, have to use the separate API's for each task to accomplish this.